# Smarty : put backslash at end of line

Tags: javascript, smarty

in `smarty` how to put backslash at end of line?
Variables with multiple line value giving error to me.

I tried `|nl2br` which put `<br />` at end of line but unable to solve my problem.

Need help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution using regex.

`|regex_replace:'/[\r\t\n]/':' '`